# Move Columnar Data to Correlation Matrix

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, multiple-columns, reorganize

I was looking for a solution (avoiding vba) to reorganize 3 columns representing data1, data2, and f(data1,data2) into a 2d array.

The data is as follows:

```
X1  X2  Z_1_2
X1  X3  Z_1_3
X1  X4  Z_1_4
X1  X5  Z_1_5
X2  X3  Z_2_3
X2  X4  Z_2_4
X2  X5  Z_2_5
X3  X4  Z_3_4
X3  X5  Z_3_5
X4  X5  Z_4_5
```

Edit: I will give some more details...

X are strings and Z are numerics.

The results should be as following:

```
     X1     X2     X3     X4     X5
X1   1      Z_1_2  Z_1_3  Z_1_4  Z_1_5
X2   Z_1_2  1      Z_2_3  Z_2_4  Z_2_5
X3   Z_1_3  Z_2_3  1      Z_3_4  Z_3_5
X4   Z_1_4  Z_2_4  Z_3_4  1      Z_4_5
X5   Z_1_5  Z_2_5  Z_3_5  Z_4_5  1
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: So what does your resulting array look like?

Comment: just a 2d array, like a correlation matrix

Comment: That does not help.  Please show your desired outcome.  The above is a 2D array.

Comment: It may be "just" that to you, but not to me!

Comment: is the data numeric?

Comment: I edited my question to make it easier

Comment: Actual data would be far more useful than what you have there - it is not at all clear what the values are meant to be like.

Comment: One recomendation, change the title to reflect what is really being asked; "Move Columnar Data to Correlation Matrix" or something like that.  To most excel user a 2D array is one that had data both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Thanks Scott, it is done, I am not really used to the lexicology for Excel users, i am more of a programmer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to set up the headers, correctly both the row and column headers.

[image]

Then if the Upper left cell put this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C,MATCH($G2&"|"&H$1,$A:$A&"|"&$B:$B,0)),IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(H$1&"|"&$G2,$A:$A&"|"&$B:$B,0)),1))
```

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just enter.  Copy and fill the rest of the array.

[image]

**One warning** this will take time to compute,  It can be sped up by limting the full column references to only those with data; `$C:$C` in this instance would be `$C$1:$C$10`.

Answer (score 2):

something like that?

```
=IF(F$1=$E2,1,INDEX($C$1:$C$10,IFERROR(MATCH(F$1&"_"&$E2,$A$1:$A$10&"_"&$B$1:$B$10,),MATCH($E2&"_"&F$1,$A$1:$A$10&"_"&$B$1:$B$10,))))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

if you get worried by the `&` you can avoid it like this:

```
=IF(F$1=$E2,1,INDEX($C$1:$C$10,MAX(ROW($1:$10)*((F$1=$A$1:$A$10)*($E2=$B$1:$B$10)+($E2=$A$1:$A$10)*(F$1=$B$1:$B$10)))))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I like your approach. +1

Comment: @ScottCraner i added a "avoid using `&`" do have a difference between our answers ^^;